# How to get Visual Studio Mac Community Edition is limited to use netstandard2.0?

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I downloaded Visual Studio for Mac community edition. After updating it, I am noticing that it seems to be limited to netstandard1.5. I want a later version than that because I want to use WebClient. How do I do that?

here are the details of my install

> Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac Version 8.6.5 (build 23)
> Installation UUID: 1e27c5df-81d5-412d-97ee-b336e256b219   GTK+ 2.24.23
> (Raleigh theme)   Xamarin.Mac 6.18.0.23 (d16-6 / 088c73638)
>
> Package version: 610000104
>
> Mono Framework MDK Runtime:   Mono 6.10.0.104 (2019-12/5d03a6fe116)
> (64-bit)  Package version: 610000104
>
> Roslyn (Language Service)
> 3.6.0-3.20210.9+4eafdcb1bcbd8d3573f2ba6065e56d9b9ce4f8a3
>
> NuGet Version: 5.6.0.6591
>
> .NET Core SDK SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.301/Sdks SDK
> Versions:
> 3.1.301
> 3.0.100
> 2.1.302 MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.10.0/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks
>
> .NET Core Runtime Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet Runtime
> Versions:
> 3.1.5
> 3.0.0
> 2.1.19
> 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... I created the wrong project type, so it was limiting me to netstandard1.5. When I deleted it and recreated it as a standard library, it then showed me netstandard2.1